# Vertical alignment in tabularray longtable

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularray

I am using the following code, but not getting the vertical middle alignment, as the image shows below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[latin]{babel} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {my table caption.},
    ]{hlines, vlines,
        colspec = {X[0.2,c,m] X[0.1,c,m] X[0.1,c,m]
            X[0.6,cmd={\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}]},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
    A & B & C & D \\
    2022 & 2022 & 2022 & \lipsum[1-1][1-3] \\
    2023 & 2023 & 2023 & \lipsum[2-4][3] \\ 
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Could you please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the cells is dominated by the last column. You'll need to vertically centre this column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[latin]{babel} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {my table caption.},
    ]{hlines, vlines,
        colspec = {X[0.2,c] X[0.1,c] X[0.1,c]
            X[0.6,cmd={\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}},m]},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
    A & B & C & D \\
    2022 & 2022 & 2022 & \lipsum[1-1][1-3] \\
    2023 & 2023 & 2023 & \lipsum[2-4][3] \\ 
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks: that fixes the issue!

Comment: @PaulS You're welcome!